# Debounce multiple form fields state update on browser's auto complete

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, onchange, debouncing, react-forms

I'm working on a dynamic form with a shared onchange method for updating the react state. Because of the UI framework I'm using, I have to utilize debounce. I made a debounce function similar to this. When the user fills out the form manually, everything works well, however when we choose stored addresses in the browser with auto complete, it doesn't work. It only takes last input value and updates the state

Could you please advise on how to update all the entries when the browser auto-fills the form with remembered addresses? Providing the functions listed below

Form Component Code

```
{
 "name": "abc"
 "email": "abc@gmail.com"
 ...//these are generated dynamically
}

const updateFormState = debounce((name: any, value: any) => {
    setFormData((prevState: any)=>{
        return {
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }
    })
});

const handleInputData = (e: Input.ChangeEvent) => {
    const name = (e as Input.InputEvent)?.currentTarget?.name;
    const value = (e as Input.InputEvent)?.currentTarget?.value;
    updateFormState(name, value)
}

const handleDropdownData = (e: Dropdown.ChangeEvent) => {
    const name = (e as Dropdown.ChangeEvent)?.currentTarget?.name;
    const value = (e as Dropdown.ChangeEvent)?.currentTarget?.value;
    updateFormState(name, value);
}
```

Debounce function code

```
const debounce = (callbackFn:any, time: number = 250) => {
let timeout: any;
return (...args: Array<any>) => {
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(()=>{
        callbackFn(...args);
    }, time)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about `oninput` event instead of `onchange` on input tag?

The difference is that the `oninput` event occurs immediately after the content has been changed, while `onchange` occurs when the element loses focus.